# SolidWorks 2020 Change GPU To AMD Radeon Pro WX 3200

Tags: amd-radeon, 3d, dual-gpu, solidworks

I have 2 GPUs Installed.

1. Nvidia 2080 Super
2. AMD Radeon Pro WX 3200

My Solidworks 2020 keeps using Nvidia one, but I want Solidworks to use AMD Radeon Pro WX 3200, a certificated GPU.

I can't find any solution over google, and the result I found is more with Integrated GPU.

Is there any way to force Solidworks to use AMD GPU rather than Nvidia? I have even added Solidworks into AMD Graphic settings to enable the performance, but no luck.

All I want to do is enable RealView Graphics.

Comment: Does this help: https://www.howtogeek.com/351522/how-to-choose-which-gpu-a-game-uses-on-windows-10/

Comment: I have tried that also; for High Performance, I can only see 2080 Super :

see the screenshots here:
1. [Windows Graphic Settings](https://prnt.sc/26dcdcq)

2. [Task Manager Screenshot](https://prnt.sc/26dcdt7)